# Convert Spring MVC to Spring BOOT

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I'm converting admin module of a Spring MVC project to Spring Boot. After adding dependencies in POM.xml, the jar files are not automatically added to the classpath and I don't see a folder named MAVEN DEPENDENCIES with all the spring boot jars added automatically. PLEASE HELP :)

`
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.tais.idare
    admin
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    war
    iDARE - Admin

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<build>
    <finalName>admin</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- 
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:unchecked</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>       
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${tomcat.webapp.dir}</webappDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
         -->     
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build> 


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.taistech.Main</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->


        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tais.iDARE</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tais.iDARE</groupId>
        <artifactId>feeds</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <!--  Spring core & mvc  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson library required for spring for automatic bean to json conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
     <!-- MySql --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  <!--    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

`

Comment: What is your IDE? you can also `mvn clean install`

Comment: Eclipse. Yes i have tried maven clean and install

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml

Comment: Spring boot creates uber jars by default, you won't have any maven dependencies folder. Make sure you are using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build your project. Show us your pom.xml .

Comment: Yes, I'm using spring-boot-maven-plugin and edited the post with my pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If spring boot Application is missing maven plugin then add it in pom.xml file as the following

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```